# How to optimize multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, queue, multiprocessing

*EDIT:
I've had questions about what the video stream is, so I will offer more clarity. The stream is a live video feed from my webcam, accessed via OpenCV. I get each frame as the camera reads it, and send it to a separate process for processing. The process returns text based on computations done on the image. The text is then displayed onto the image. I need to display the stream in realtime, and it is ok if there is a lag between the text and the video being shown (i.e. if the text was applicable to a previous frame, that's ok).*

*Perhaps an easier way to think of this is that I'm doing image recognition on what the webcam sees. I send one frame at a time to a separate process to do recognition analysis on the frame, and send the text back to be put as a caption on the live feed. Obviously the processing takes more time than simply grabbing frames from the webcam and showing them, so if there is a delay in what the caption is and what the webcam feed shows, that's acceptable and expected.*

*What's happening now is that the live video I'm displaying is lagging due to the other processes (when I don't send frames to the process for computing, there is no lag). I've also ensured only one frame is enqueued at a time so avoid overloading the queue and causing lag. I've updated the code below to reflect this detail.*

I'm using the multiprocessing module in python to help speed up my main program. However I believe I might be doing something incorrectly, as I don't think the computations are happening quite in parallel.

I want my program to read in images from a video stream in the main process, and pass on the frames to two child processes that do computations on them and send text back (containing the results of the computations) to the main process.

However, the main process seems to lag when I use multiprocessing, running about half as fast as without it, leading me to believe that the processes aren't running completely in parallel.

After doing some research, I surmised that the lag may have been due to communicating between the processes using a queue (passing an image from the main to the child, and passing back text from child to main).

However I commented out the computational step and just had the main process pass an image and the child return blank text, and in this case, the main process did not slow down at all. It ran at full speed.

Thus I believe that either

1) I am not optimally using multiprocessing

OR

2) These processes cannot truly be run in parallel (I would understand a little lag, but it's slowing the main process down in half).

Here's a outline of my code. There is only one consumer instead of 2, but both consumers are nearly identical. If anyone could offer guidance, I would appreciate it.

```
class Consumer(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, task_queue, result_queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue
        #other initialization stuff

    def run(self):
        while True:
            image = self.task_queue.get()
            #Do computations on image
            self.result_queue.put("text")

        return

import cv2

tasks = multiprocessing.Queue()
results = multiprocessing.Queue()
consumer = Consumer(tasks,results)
consumer.start()

#Creating window and starting video capturer from camera
cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#Try to get the first frame
if vc.isOpened():
    rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
    rval = False

while rval:
    if tasks.empty():
       tasks.put(image)
    else:
       text = tasks.get()
       #Add text to frame
       cv2.putText(frame,text)

    #Showing the frame with all the applied modifications
    cv2.imshow("preview", frame)

    #Getting next frame from camera
    rval, frame = vc.read()
```

Comment: Your code is missing the "()" in "consumer.start()" and the consumer does not start. Typo ?

Comment: Yes that's a typo, sorry.

Answer (score 9):

> I want my program to read in images from a video stream in the main process

In producer/consumer implementations, which is what you have above, the producer, what puts tasks into the queue to be executed by the consumers, needs to be separate from the main/controlling process so that it can add tasks in parallel with the main process reading output from results queue.

Try the following. Have added a sleep in the consumer processes to simulate processing and added a second consumer to show they are being run in parallel.

It would also be a good idea to limit the size of the task queue to avoid having it run away with memory usage if processing cannot keep up with input stream. Can specify a size when calling `Queue(<size>)`. If the queue is at that size, calls to `.put` will block until the queue is not full.

```
import time
import multiprocessing
import cv2

class ImageProcessor(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, tasks_q, results_q):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.tasks_q = tasks_q
        self.results_q = results_q

    def run(self):
        while True:
            image = self.tasks_q.get()
            # Do computations on image
            time.sleep(1)
            # Display the result on stream
            self.results_q.put("text")

# Tasks queue with size 1 - only want one image queued
# for processing. 
# Queue size should therefore match number of processes
tasks_q, results_q = multiprocessing.Queue(1), multiprocessing.Queue()
processor = ImageProcessor(tasks_q, results_q)
processor.start()

def capture_display_video(vc):
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    while rval:    
        image = frame.get_image()
        if not tasks_q.full():
            tasks_q.put(image)
        if not results_q.empty():
            text = results_q.get()
            cv2.putText(frame, text)
        cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
        rval, frame = vc.read()

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not vc.isOpened():
    raise Exception("Cannot capture video")

capture_display_video(vc)
processor.terminate()
```

Comment: So I don't add to the task queue until the consumer has finished processing the image. Thus the max size is 1. However just a quick question. I need the producer to have the result of the consumer (i.e. the result queue). It does not need the result right away but rather whenever the consumer is finished. Is there a way for that to occur without any more slow down? I've edited my code to add this detail so it's more clear. Sorry for not mentioning this earlier, didn't think it was relevant.

Comment: Basically I'm adding text (result of some calculations) to the video stream (that I'm displaying). I don't need the text to appear frame by frame, it's ok if there's some delay. However the display video stream cannot lag (and that is what is currently happening).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the main process is displaying the stream? Therefore waiting for a result in the main process introduces lag? Have edited the answer to show one way to do what you want. Can pass the stream as argument to consumers and just display the result of the calculation on the stream as it becomes available. In that case, results queue is not needed. Alternatively, and I cannot say what will work without knowledge of the stream object, can have the main process read from results queue and display result with producer displaying the real time stream as is.

Comment: Updated for simplicity. Read and display stream in main process, consumer adds text as results become available. You may need to pass reference to the current frame instead of stream object, depending on the implementation.

Comment: I've updated my answer significantly to add more detail. Hopefully you understand how I'm interacting with the video from my webcam. In order to display the text on the webcam, I need the main process to have the text itself. The stream is not an object per say, but rather I'm getting frames as I ask for them. See my updated code.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful. Have updated the answer with what looks like it will work based on the implementation that you have. There is no separate producer/video  reader process anymore and the main process checks for results from queue without blocking so as not to introduce lag and displays video. A processor/consumer process gets images from queue, processes and puts results in queue. The main changes from the original code are the queue empty/full checks to avoid introducing lag. This also frees you up to raise the tasks queue size and/or create additional processor processes

Comment: I tested your answer with the full code and I got no improvements in speed. Any ideas as to what I can change?

Comment: Cannot really say without knowledge of where blocking is happening, if at all. Try profiling the code (python -m cProfile -o <output file> <your script>). See profile documentation on how to read the file or paste it somewhere. It will tell you where the script is spending most of its time

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more elegant (IMHO) solution that utilizes multiple processes for processing your frames:

```
def process_image(args):
    image, frame = args
    #Do computations on image
    return "text", frame

import cv2

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

def image_source():
    #Creating window and starting video capturer from camera
    cv2.namedWindow("preview")
    vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    #Try to get the first frame
    if vc.isOpened():
        rval, frame = vc.read()
    else:
        rval = False

    while rval:
        yield image, frame
        # Getting next frame from camera
        rval, frame = vc.read()

for (text, frame) in pool.imap(process_image, image_source()):
    # Add text to frame
    cv2.putText(frame, text)
    # Showing the frame with all the applied modifications
    cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
```

`Pool.imap` should allow you to iterate through the pool's results while it's still processing other images from your cam.

Comment: I'm confused about the logic in your code. By using `yield` it seems as though you're saving the images from the webcam and processing them all at once? I want to process them simultaneously while showing what my cam sees, so I can caption what the cam sees as it is being shown (even if there is some lag between the caption and what is actually being displayed)

Comment: `image_source()` is a generator which yields images from your webcam. `Pool.imap` consumes these images and sends them for processing in the pool's processes and returns the results as they become available. I wrote this based on your code so I'm not sure where `image` is coming from but I guess you get the idea.

Comment: To clarify, `pool.imap(process_image, image_source())` translates to: send the yielded `(image, frame)` tuples from `image_source()` for processing in the pool's processes by calling `process_image` on each consumed tuple. Meanwhile, we're consuming the results of `process_image` concurrently in the main thread and displaying the results.

Comment: I ran the code but for some reason it doesn't show anything but the program finishes up right away. I included a `cv2.waitKey(1)` but that didn't seem to do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3543300 if the program finishes up right away it means the `image_source` generator isn't yielding anything (which means `rval` is False) hence the program is never entering the loop. Try debugging it by adding some prints in `image_source` and inside the loop (or even using `pdb`).

Answer (score 2):

(Updated solution based on you last code sample)

It will get images from the stream, put one in the task queue as soon as it is available, and display the last image with the last text.

I put some active loop in there to simulate a processing longer than the time between two images.
I means that the text displayed is not necessarily the one belonging to the image, but the last one computed.
If the processing is fast enough, the shift between image and text should be limited.

Note that I force calls to get/put with some try/catch. Per the doc, empty and full are not 100% accurate.

```
import cv2
import multiprocessing
import random
from time import sleep

class Consumer(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, task_queue, result_queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue
        # Other initialization stuff

    def run(self):
        while True:
            frameNum, frameData = self.task_queue.get()
            # Do computations on image
            # Simulate a processing longer than image fetching
            m = random.randint(0, 1000000)
            while m >= 0:
                m -= 1
            # Put result in queue
            self.result_queue.put("result from image " + str(frameNum))

        return

# No more than one pending task
tasks = multiprocessing.Queue(1)
results = multiprocessing.Queue()
# Init and start consumer
consumer = Consumer(tasks,results)
consumer.start()

#Creating window and starting video capturer from camera
cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#Try to get the first frame
if vc.isOpened():
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
else:
    rval = False

# Dummy int to represent frame number for display
frameNum = 0
# String for result
text = None

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

# Process loop
while rval:
    # Grab image from stream
    frameNum += 1
    # Put image in task queue if empty
    try:
        tasks.put_nowait((frameNum, frame))
    except:
        pass
    # Get result if ready
    try:
        # Use this if processing is fast enough
        # text = results.get(timeout=0.4)
        # Use this to prefer smooth display over frame/text shift
        text = results.get_nowait()
    except:
        pass

    # Add last available text to last image and display
    print("display:", frameNum, "|", text)
    # Showing the frame with all the applied modifications
    cv2.putText(frame,text,(10,25), font, 1,(255,0,0),2)
    cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
    # Getting next frame from camera
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    # Optional image resize
    # frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
```

Here is some output, you can see the delay between image and result, and the result catching back.

```
> ('display:', 493, '|', 'result from image 483')
> ('display:', 494, '|', 'result from image 483')
> ('display:', 495, '|', 'result from image 489')
> ('display:', 496, '|', 'result from image 490')
> ('display:', 497, '|', 'result from image 495')
> ('display:', 498, '|', 'result from image 496')
```

Comment: I think you understand the problem I'm having. However I'm wondering how your solution solves the initial problem I have, which was that there was a lag in the main process loop (i.e. delay in displaying images).

Comment: I does send the image to be processed without blocking the main loop. Try ```tasks.get_nowait()``` if you want no wait at all (at the risk of a bigger shift between image and text). Dumb question, if you do not send the image to the consumer and put some dumb text on each image (like datetime.now()), is everything running without any lag ? Did you check that you use more than one CPU core when both processes are active ?

Comment: If I do not send the image to the consumer, there is no lag. I tried passing dummy text back as a result and the program ran smoothly. How do I check if more than one CPU core is being used? I'm on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Updated my solution based on you code. I don't see lagging on my side. To check you CPU usage, find the task manager from Ubuntu. If you have a terminal at hand type ```top``` to display the live process list, then ```ocpu (enter)``` (o: sort, cpu: by CPU usage). On my hand I see 2 Python processes at the top. One close to 100%, one around 40%.

Comment: I haven't gotten to test it out completely yet, but just wondering that other than the forced calls to get/put, are you doing anything differently than me? Was that all that was "likely" causing the lag?

Comment: FYI, bare excepts like the above are a no-no. They will stop the program from exiting as they catch all exceptions including base and system ones like SystemExit.

Comment: Not much, but adding the nowait and the timeout can make a difference. Your code will wait for an item to be ready in the queue and block. You can try to put some logging in your code with timestamps to check where it lags exactly. And Danny is right, my try catch blocks are ugly. Just wanted to test quickly. You should explicitly catch only exceptions from the Queue.

Comment: I tested your answer with the full code and I got no improvements in speed. Any ideas as to what I can change?

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest you a slightly different approach, with a lot less "red tape". I think the main problem is that you are overlooking the main way to communicate with a process: it is through its arguments and return values. If you can send the frame data as an argument, there is no need of queues or pipes or other methods.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process_frame(frame_id, frame_data):
    # this function simulates the processing of the frame.
    # I used a longer sleep thinking that it takes longer
    # and therefore the reason of parallel processing.
    print("..... got frame {}".format(frame_id))
    time.sleep(.5)
    char = frame_data[frame_id]
    count = frame_data.count(char)
    return frame_id, char, count

def process_result(res):
    # this function simulates the function that would receive
    # the result from analyzing the frame, and do what is
    # appropriate, like printing, making a dict, saving to file, etc.
    # this function is called back when the result is ready.
    frame_id, char, count = res
    print("in frame {}".format(frame_id), \
           ", character '{}' appears {} times.".format(
                        chr(char), count))



if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = Pool(4)
    # in my laptop I got these times:
    # workers, time
    #   1     10.14
    #   2      5.22
    #   4      2.91
    #   8      2.61 # no further improvement after 4 workers.
                    # your case may be different though.

    from datetime import datetime as dt
    t0 = dt.now()

    for i in range(20):   # I limited this loop to simulate 20 frames
                          # but it could be a continuous stream,
                          # that when finishes should execute the
                          # close() and join() methods to finish
                          # gathering all the results.


        # The following lines simulate the video streaming and
        # your selecting the frames that you need to analyze and
        # send to the function process_frame.
        time.sleep(0.1)
        frame_id = i
        frame_data = b'a bunch of binary data representing your frame'

        pool.apply_async(  process_frame,                #func
                           (frame_id, frame_data),       #args
                           callback=process_result       #return value
                        )

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(dt.now() - t0)
```

I think that this simpler approach would be enough for your program. No need of using classes or queues.

Comment: The reason I want to use multiprocessing is because I'm getting a video stream (i.e. a webcam). I want to display the stream in real time. And I send an image from the stream to a processing function, that returns text. When the processing function is done, I add the text to the stream that is being displayed in the main process, and then send the next frame to be processed (so there is a delay with regards to the text, as it applies to a previous frame). Is there a way to modify your approach such that I can keep displaying the stream in real time without having to wait for the result.

Comment: @user3543300 I would like to have more information about your code... How are you streaming your video source?, How often you tag a frame for processing? How long it takes to process that frame and return a result? I think your problem description is a bit... skimpy. Nevertheless, I tried my best to adapt my approach with the new hints I get from your comment above. But because this code is significantly different than the one in this answer, I will post a new answer with the new version. I hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comment to my previous answer, I understood your problem a 'bit' better. I would like to have more information about your code/problem. Anyway, and because this code is significantly different than my previous answer, I decided to provide another answer. I won't comment the code too much though, because you can follow it from my previous answer. I will use text instead of images, just to simulate the process.

The following code prints a letter out of "lorem ipsum", selecting one out of 6 letters (frames). Because there is a lag, we need a buffer that I implemented with a deque. After the buffer has advanced, the displaying of the frame and caption are in sync.

I don't know how often you tag a frame, or how much it really takes to process it, but you can have an educated guess with this code by playing with some of the variables.

```
import time
import random
random.seed(1250)
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
from collections import deque


def display_stream(stream, pool, queue, buff, buffered=False):
    delay = 24
    popped_frames = 0
    for i, frame in enumerate(stream):
        buff.append([chr(frame), ''])
        time.sleep(1/24 * random.random()) # suppose a 24 fps video
        if i % 6 == 0:                     # suppose one out of 6 frames
            pool.apply_async(process_frame, (i, frame, queue))
        ii, caption = (None, '') if queue.empty() else queue.get()
        if buffered:
            if ii is not None:
                buff[ii - popped_frames][1] = caption
            if i > delay:
                print(buff.popleft())
                popped_frames += 1
        else:
            lag = '' if ii is None else i - ii
            print(chr(frame), caption, lag)

    else:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        if buffered:
            try:
                while True:
                    print(buff.popleft())
            except IndexError:
                pass


def process_frame(i, frame, queue):
    time.sleep(0.4 * random.random())      # suppose ~0.2s to process
    caption = chr(frame).upper()           # mocking the result...
    queue.put((i, caption))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    p = Pool()
    q = Manager().Queue()
    d = deque()

    stream = b'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'

    display_stream(stream, p, q, b)
```

Comment: I added a lot more detail to my answers, and updated my code. Hopefully that helps?

Answer (score -2):

You could try setting the affinity mask to make sure each process runs on a different core. I use this on windows 7.

```
def setaffinity(mask = 128): # 128 is core 7
    pid    = win32api.GetCurrentProcessId()
    handle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, True, pid)
    win32process.SetProcessAffinityMask(handle, mask)
    return
```

Comment: Affinity is for pinning processes to specific cores. The OS scheduler already ensures that multiple processes will run on different cores when available.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: Is there a similar method for Ubuntu (16.04)?

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu, but I found a man page for `sched_setaffinity,  sched_getaffinity`  -  set  and  get  a thread's CPU affinity mask `http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html` that seems to do the trick.

Comment: Reference for affinity? "Processor affinity, or CPU pinning enables the binding and unbinding of a process or a thread to a central processing unit" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity and http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6799